# Encoding mp4 to other

Tags: android, azure, video-encoding

We have uploaded several videos from android to windows azure cloud.
the videos (by default mp4) were uploaded as blobs to the storage container.

I've seen that there's Media Service which has the option to convert *.mp4 to other extensions.

My issues are:
- How to connect automatically all blobs to the media service?
- Is it possible to run tasks from android to the media service? (So far we found only .net solutions).

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly use Media Services to convert your H.264 MP4 file to other formats!

First, I suggest that you get yourself familiar with the Media Services itself - concepts, how it works.

Next, you can check the [Media Services REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh973617.aspx), which can be used from any platform, not just .NET. Currently there is no Andorid SDK for Media Services, but there is a good "[Building Applications with Media Services REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973618)" documentation.

Once you get through the documentation, I suggest that you make a small change to your code that uploads file to Azure Blob Container. It is really small. Instead of uploading to Blob storage directly, you can:

1. [Create an empty asset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh974277.aspx#create_an_asset)
2. [Create a SAS Locator for that asset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh974308.aspx#create_a_locator) (type 1)
   2.1. to create a Locator, you will need to first [create an Access Policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh974297.aspx#create_an_accesspolicy) for the locator. You ned to specify the access policy as Write (permissions: 2) to be able to upload.
3. Upload the MP4 video using the SAS Locator - just like the way you upload to a normal blob storage.

At this point you will have a Media Asset which you can convert to various other formats.